# Dependency issues with multi-module maven web project in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, maven

I'm creating a multi-module project with a flat hierarchy in Eclipse:

¦ myproject-parent
¦ - pom.xml
¦ myproject
¦ - pom.xml
¦ myproject-dep
¦ - pom.xml

With the parent pom having references to the two modules, `myproject` has `myproject-dep` in its dependencies and both have the parent noted. The project and subproject dependencies are complete in the `web/WEB-INF/lib` folder for Tomcat.

`myproject` is a (dynamic) web project with compiled classes going to `myproject/web/WEB-INF/classes`, while the dependency project's classes go into `myproject-dep/target/classes`. `myproject` is run on Tomcat and `myproject-dep` is a required project on the build path.

In this situation, I would expect all the dependencies to be in order but the Catalina class loader can't find `myproject-dep`'s classes. If I add these to the tomcat classpath explicitly in the run configurations then it fails by not finding jar's from `myproject-dep` that are clearly present in the webapps's lib folder.

What have I missed here?
Thanks!

Comment: Can put the poms here to take a deeper look how your build looks like?

Answer (score 0):

You say that you are building with maven, but it doesn't sound like you are packaging your war with maven.

If you were using the maven-war-plugin, it would already pull your declared dependencies into the war when it goes through the packaging phase.  This also assumes that the dependencies have a properly declared scope, which in your case sounds like the default of **compile**.